# Issue with getting my API Call in Rails to properly display correctly in views (Using HTTParty)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, api-design, httparty

I am using HTTParty gem in Rails to make my API call and it has been successful. I receive no errors however after defining the variables in my controller I can not get my loops to produce anything.

If I type in <%= @variable %> it shows just the Active Record object which I expected. If I do the same but include variable.name it provides a string, but not exactly what I was hoping. I have followed several HTTParty tutorials and put in a lot of API research but I can't seem to get this figured out. I am trying to retrieve a list of snacks from an external API. Here is what I have (some of the things in my view is just to test).

API Call (I put in separate folder services):

```
    class SnackAPI
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://api-snacks.nerderylabs.com/v1/'
  SNACK_ACCESS = "/snacks?ApiKey=#{ENV['SNACK_API_KEY']}"

  def get_snacks
    response = self.class.get(SNACK_ACCESS)
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

First time posting code snippets so not sure how to post in with proper indentation, but it is correct in my application.

Controller:

```
class SnacksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @snacks = Snack.all
    @permanent_snacks = Snack.where(optional: false)
    @optional_snacks = Snack.where(optional: true)
  end
end
```

Model:

```
    class Snack < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

View (index.html.erb) in snacks folder:

```
    <h1> Welcome to SnaFoo! </h1>

<!-- I am attempting to get these loops to display each snack item included in the API but nothing appears -->

<% @permanent_snacks.each do |snack| %>
  <%= snack.name %>
<% end %>

<% @optional_snacks.each do |snack| %>
  <%= snack.name %>
<% end %>

<%= @snacks %>
<%= @optional_snacks %>
<%= @permanent_snacks %>

<br  />

Snack with name paramater (to test):

<%= @snacks.name %>

<!-- So it recognizes the fields and datatypes -->
```

Results in View: The objects themselves (  for each one. I expected this, it was just to test the API was retrieving info) For the <%= @snacks.name %> it outputs Snack so it is at least recognizing my fields and datatypes in my schema. The main issue is getting the loops to work and display each snack in the API.

I have tried for hours attempting to resolve this on my own but I'm at a point of frustration and would appreciate any help that could point me in the right direction.

If Schema is needed/helpful to help resolve this I can post that too.

Terminal output when I load page (usually code on Ubuntu but am coding this on Windows due to some issues with my partition:

> Started GET "/" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-09-11 21:49:49 +0000 Cannot
>   render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1,
>   127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255 Processing by SnacksController#index as HTML   Rendering snacks/index.html.erb within layouts/application   Snack
>   Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "snacks".* FROM "snacks" WHERE
>   "snacks"."optional" = $1  [["optional", "f"]]   Snack Load (0.5ms) 
>   SELECT "snacks".* FROM "snacks" WHERE "snacks"."optional" = $1 
>   [["optional", "t"]]   Rendered snacks/index.html.erb within
>   layouts/application (3.5ms) Completed 200 OK in 401ms (Views: 374.1ms
>   | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)

Answer (score 0):

Start by fixing the client:

```
# place this in /lib or app/clients as it is not a service object.
# app/clients/snack_api.rb
class SnackAPI
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://api-snacks.nerderylabs.com/v1/'
  format :json

  def initialize(*opts)
    @options = opts.reverse_merge({
      ApiKey: ENV['SNACK_API_KEY']
    })
  end
  def get_snacks
    response = self.class.get('/snacks', @options)
  end
end
```

Use `format :json` instead of instead of parsing the JSON response manually. This is very important since if the API errors out and returns an empty response JSON.parse blows up:

```
irb(main):002:0> JSON.parse('')
JSON::ParserError: 745: unexpected token at ''
```

If you just want to display articles straight from the API you don't need a model:

```
class SnacksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    response = SnackAPI.get_snacks

    if response.success?
      @snacks = response[:snacks]
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Could not fetch snacks"
      @snacks = []
    end
  end
end
```

Otherwise create a service object to consume the API:

```
# app/services/snack_import_service
class SnackImportService

  attr_accessor :client

  def intialize(client = nil, **opts)
    # this is a trick that lets you inject a spy or double in tests
    @client = client || SnackAPI.new(opts)
  end

  def perform
    response = client.get_snacks
    # Remember that HTTP requests can and will fail
    if response.success?
      response[:snacks].map do |data|
        Snack.find_or_create_by!(name: data[:name])
      end
    else
      Rails.logger.error "SnackAPI request was unsuccessful #{response.code}"
    end
  end
end
```

Having this as a separate service object from the client is a good idea as it adheres to the single responsibility principle and lets you even extract out the client to a gem as a reusable component that is separate from your application logic.

```
class SnacksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @snacks = SnackImportService.new.perform
    @permanent_snacks = Snack.where(optional: false)
    @optional_snacks = Snack.where(optional: true)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of the information. One question about the reverse_merge method used. I couldn't find great details about what exactly it does in general much less in this instance. Would you care to explain what it is doing in the client?

Comment: Also just to clarify, either put the API Call in client or lib or make it a service. Or do both? Just curious as I see no get call in the SnackImportService. Again thank you so much. I have not seen it done like this in all of my exploring for answers and guides. I will test it out asap

Comment: Sorry for spamming the comments, one last thing that slipped my mind. Once I implement the API Call this way, my loops to show the snacks should work correctly?

Comment: Again another question. Could you elaborate on your comment in the SnackImportService (# this is a trick that lets you inject a spy or double in tests). Thanks again, hopefully I can start to piece these things together on my own

Comment: Ok so I implemented each one of these changes, except for your change to the controller as there is something I have to do later with the optional snacks and still nothing shows from the loops in my view. Also in my controller with the @snacks = SnackImportService.new.perform it comes back with an error saying undefined method 'perform'. Do I need to put require './services/snack_import_service' in my controller or put any require statements anywhere given that I am putting classes outside of the premade rails directory? The main issue is that the snacks still show nothing.

Comment: `.reverse_merge` is like merge but the other way around. Its really handy for filling in the passed options with defaults. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-reverse_merge

Comment: `response = client.get_snacks` - its the first line

Comment: This is basically just dependency injection - by injecting the client you can replace it with a stub in a unit test without mucking about in the internals of the class.

Comment: If you put the files in `/app/services` rails will autoload the files so you don't need to require them. If the file was not loaded you would get a`Uninitialized Constant` error. Rather maybe you should try breaking the problem down and doing some basic debugging. You can use byebug to set a breakpoint and then you can inspect the `@snacks` variable. Also note that I have no idea what the api returns - you need to actually finalize the code yourself.

Comment: After performing inspect on snacks the output was an Active record object with all fields in my schema set as nil. Here is an example of what the API contains `Sample:
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Gorp",
    "optional": true,
    "purchaseLocations":  "John's Grocery, Corner C-Store",
    "purchaseCount": 0,
    "lastPurchaseDate": null
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "Bacon Jerky",
    "optional": false,
    "purchaseLocations": "John's Grocery",
    "purchaseCount": 542,
    "lastPurchaseDate": "9/11/2017"
  }
]`

Comment: I want to figure this out on my own but I am in sort of uncharted waters so am looking for a little assistance in moving in the right direction. The permanent snacks have optional: false and optional snacks as true. I created a migration to add the fields manually so I figure that could play a role as I assume the API should provide the proper data. After rolling back all migrations I now have nothing in my schema and deleted the Snack model however it appears I may need a snack model or something of the sort as now I receive uninitialized constant for Snack.

Comment: I will also be performing a post request to update the API as a suggest a snack feature using a dropdown list as well as a text box with submit button. I think once I get a grasp on this I will be able to implement that, hopefully. Right now I just want to focus on getting the API contents to display what I need. I understand I am quite the novice when it comes to API usage and so thank you for putting up with my lack of expertise. And I am still confused on whether I need both the API call in the client as well as the SnackImportService or if I just need one or the other?

Comment: I have been reading up on Jobs in the rails guides. I have never used them before, but they seem like they could be of use. I am truly lost at this point otherwise. My schema takes over the API data so `@snacks.inspect` just results in nil as there are no snacks in my database. I cant seem to figure out how to get the `SELECT "snacks".*FROM "snacks" WHERE "snacks"."optional" = true/false` from the API snacks rather than the non-existant ones in database. Also unsure why but in the console the select statement loads snack where `"optional" = $1 [["optional","f"]]`

Comment: I wish I could pay you for this. If you have crypto currency/wallets for them I would be happy to. As it stands, given that I can't seem to get the GET to work I am feeling as though I will need guidance for POSTing new snacks to the API as this must be done through a text form which I presume I will need to do a form action, so I will look more into that. But for the controller I have a piece of code that I was wondering if you could tell me whether it would work properly given my setup. I will post in next comment because it doesn't let me add enough characters along with this. So here it is

Comment: ` def post_snack(snacks)                                                        
     snacks.each do |snack| options = 
 {body {name:snack.name, location:snack.purchase_location, last_purchased: snack.last_purchased }.to_json,
   headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}}
   response = self.class.post(SNACK_ACCESS, options)` With proper indendation. By the way if you are fed up with me I fully understand..You've introduced me to some new concepts that should help me in the long run. And again I would be happy to pay you for your time and help. Ideally through cryptocurrency.